# What is this chord progression?

Tags: chord-progressions, negative-harmony

There is a chord progression in Nasty Majesty (Track 2 in Octotune, from Splatoon 2) that I am having trouble analyzing.
It is:
`Gminor Bflat Cminor D7 Gminor`
and I am not sure how to analyze it.

I tried analyzing it with the “negative harmony” approach, and I got:

- Gminor: tonic
- Bflat: tonic-parallel
- Cminor: dominant
- D7: dominant, from major

Something did not feel right about this (why would a C be dominant in G?), so I tried an approach similar to analyzing in a major key:

- Gminor: tonic
- Bflat: ambiguous (is it the dominant-parallel? or the tonic-counterparallel? likely the tonic-counterparallel because it follows a tonic)
- Cminor: subdominant
- D7: dominant

I am not sure how to analyze this. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The progression seems to be in G min.  Relative to that key Gmin is i, Bb is III, C- is iv and D7 is V7.  Seems to be the most direct way to analyze it.

Answer (score 3):

i III iv V7 i - assuming the key is in G minor

It looks like a simple Tonic - Predominant - Dominant - tonic progression

For Negative theory (Neo Riemannian to take place, I would expect a chord to take place with a Db tonic, thus expanding on the m3 difference between Gm's tonic and BbM's tonic. Whether Db major or Db minor / respelled to C# minor were to appear, I would then assume to also see E major or minor appear, thus completing an octatonic cycle based on Gdimo7 pitches (though enharmonically spelled at times.)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I know that is an “i-flatIII-iv-V7”. Also, we have TWO predominants (Bflat, Cminor).

Comment: @1gr8penguin what additional information are you looking for?

Comment: What the functions are exactly (T/D/S)

Answer (score 0):

Gm, B♭, Cm, D7. Let's say it's in key B♭.

Gm= vi submediant

B♭ = I tonic

Cm = ii supertonic

D7 = V7/vi secondary dominant (of submediant).

Putting it into key Gm

Gm = i tonic

B♭ = III mediant

Cm = iv subdominant

D7 = V dominant

B♭ and Gm are *relative* major/minor. *Parallels* will have the same tonic.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I know it is in G minor.

Comment: What exactly are you aware of? Terms like 'dominant-parallel' and 'tonic counter-parallel' are not known to me.  That Bb is the relative major - mediant in key Gm, R.N. III.

Answer (score 0):

No need for 'negative harmony' or any other complicated explanation.  It's just the hoary old '4 chord trick' - that 'Heart and Soul' thing that your kid sister bashes out interminably on the piano with her friend - modified for minor tonality.

In a major key it's I, vi, IV, V7.    The three Primary Triads plus the Relative Minor.

In a minor key it's still tonic, subdominant, dominant 7th. That's Gm, Cm, D7.  But the additional chord is now bIII, the Relative Major.

For hundreds of years, V of a minor key was almost ALWAYS major.   Not quite so inevitable now, but you shouldn't be surprised when it is!

(And, as @Tim has pointed out, your chord-naming is shaky.  The parallel major has the SAME root.  Bb is the relative major of G minor.)